# Any apps/sites to vectorize images for free?

Tags: image-processing, image-editor, vector-graphics, image, sketch

I drew some diagrams in a mobile Android sketch app and submitted them to a publisher, but he says the image resolution is poor and he wants vector versions. Freelancers charge hefty prices. I found some online sites that vectorize images for a monthly subscription. Are there any apps/sites that can do this for free?

Answer (score 11):

In the apps category (Windows, Mac, Linux), one can use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/release/) to perform a [trace bitmap operation](https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tracing-an-image.html). The results are usually of reasonable quality and may require some manipulation of the parameters incorporated into the feature.

It also may be more practical, if you have a computer with the above operating system, to create the diagram directly within Inkscape, to ensure maximum quality with minimum effort.

Comment: I have spent many many hours of my life tracing bitmapped images in Inkscape. It is rare that an image is simple enough for the trace bitmap operation to work the way you'd like, and most of the time I end up either touching up a lot or just redoing the whole thing. I just tried Vectorizer, Vector Magic, and autotracer. Vectorizer and Vector Magic looked pretty good, but they're not free.

Comment: I agree that Inkscape can be challenging for more complex images. The OP did not provide a sample. In the second paragraph, I suggested creation directly within Inkscape to perhaps make the task easier.

Comment: @bfris And what about autotracer and the other 4 free ones?

Comment: @convert autotracer is not nearly as good as the two paid options. It's probably closer to Inkscape. Inkscape does do OK for some images.

Comment: @bfris And the other 4 links?

Answer (score 2):

Have not tried it from mobile device, but [Free Online Converter](https://online-converting.com/autotrace//) should be exactly what you asking. You can try [PNG to SVG](https://www.pngtosvg.com/) as well. And there are even more sites like [autotracer](https://www.autotracer.org/) and [Vectorization](https://www.vectorization.org/) for example or [TextCompare](https://www.textcompare.org/vectorize/).

Comment: Potrace (through Sourceforge) is another free option. Been ages since I last used it though. YMMV.

Comment: Vectormagic isn't free, though.

Comment: @Joey Sorry my fault, the same problem with Vectorizer, both can convert images, but downloading is then a problem. Will edit my answer and replace that recomendations by more suitable ones.

Comment: @Stax But Potrace not working oN Android, as far I saw.